# Spark scala method combinations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

guys I have a problem with the method combinations

My code :

```html
val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("aaa bbb bbb"))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> myRDD.foreach{println}
aaa bbb bbb

scala> myRDD.map(_.split(" ")).flatMap(_.combinations(2)).
     | map(p=>(p.mkString(","),1)).
     | reduceByKey(_+_).
     | foreach{println}
(aaa,bbb,1)
(bbb,bbb,1)
```

I dont' why the output is not

```html
(aaa,bbb,2)
(bbb,aaa,2)
(bbb,bbb,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#combinations(n:Int):Iterator%5BRepr%5D) covers this pretty well I think:

> Iterates over combinations. A *combination* of length n is a subsequence of the original sequence, with the elements taken in order. Thus, **"xy" and "yy" are both length-2 combinations of "xyy", but "yx" is not**. If there is more than one way to generate the same subsequence, only one will be returned.
>
> For example, **"xyyy" has three different ways to generate "xy"** depending on whether the first, second, or third "y" is selected. However, **since all are identical, only one will be chosen**. Which of the three will be taken is an implementation detail that is not defined.

In your specific case this breaks down to something like:

```
(aaa, bbb)
(aaa, bbb) //Thrown out since it duplicates the first
(bbb, bbb)
```

Answer (score 1):

In combination function , a ***combination* of length  n is the subsequence of the original sequence, with elements taken in order**. So in your case, for (aaa,bbb,bbb) the possible subsequences are (aaa,bbb) and (bbb,bbb) but not (bbb,aaa) .

Please refer [scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#combinations(n:Int):Iterator[Repr])